# Migrating data between DSE 4.6.7 and DSE 5.1.3

Tags: cassandra

Currently I have DSE 4.6.7 with Cassandra 2.0.14. I am building another cluster with DSE 5.1.3 and cassandra 3.11. I would like to migrate the tables from DSE 4.6.7 to DSE 5.1.3. Will that work.

Instead of upgrade of existing cluster. I am creating a new one and would like to migrate the data. Will that work.

Comment: You have multiple options depending on the data size. You can do an ETL from your old cluster to the new one. On the other hand you get the SSTables from the old cluster and then do `nodetool upgradesstables`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Let me check and get back.